# Log4net buffer not flushing when full in lossy setup

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, log4net, log4net-configuration, log4net-appender

I'm using Log4net ElasticSearchAppender in my C# webAPI with a `BufferSize` of **10** and `Lossy` set to **true** to preserve performance, as seen here : 
https://github.com/bruno-garcia/log4net.ElasticSearch/wiki/02-Appender-Settings

> `<lossy value="false"/>`Log4net.ElasticSearch uses a buffer to collect
>   events and then flush them to the Elasticsearch server on a background
>   thread. Setting this value to true will cause log4net.Elasticsearch to
>   begin discarding events if the buffer is full and has not been
>   flushed. This could happen if the Elasticsearch server becomes
>   unresponsive or goes offline.

I also set the evaluator to `ERROR`, that will force the flushing of the buffer anyway if an ERROR occurs.

Here's the associated config file :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<log4net>
    <appender name="ElasticSearchAppender" type="log4net.ElasticSearch.ElasticSearchAppender, log4net.ElasticSearch">
    <threshold value="ALL" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout,log4net">
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
    </layout>
    <connectionString value="Server=my-elasticsearch-server;Index=foobar;Port=80;rolling=true;mode=tcp"/>
    <lossy value="true" />
    <bufferSize value="10" />
    <evaluator type="log4net.Core.LevelEvaluator">
      <threshold value="ERROR" />
    </evaluator>
  </appender>
  <root>
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="ElasticSearchAppender" />
  </root>
</log4net>
```

Here's the behaviour I get :
the flushing triggered by an ERROR (evaluator) is working fine, but `INFO` or `DEBUG` messages alone **are never flushed to Elastic**, even if there are 10, 20, or 100 of them.

The buffer does never flush when full in this configuration, it just keeps discarding `DEBUG`  or `INFO` logs until an `ERROR` comes out, even though Elastic is online and perfectly responsive.

Note: I tried setting `lossy` to false, and the buffer flushes when full. But I'm affraid this would damage my application responsiveness too much.

Am I gettings something wrong? 
Is there a better way to log while minimizing performance impact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After testing the behaviour, here's what I found :

The buffer becoming full does **never** trigger a flushing when `lossy` is true.

[Bruno garcia](https://github.com/bruno-garcia/log4net.ElasticSearch/wiki/02-Appender-Settings)'s article was quite misleading about the `Lossy` property, especially this sentence :

> Setting this value to true will cause (...) to begin discarding events if the buffer is full (...). This could happen **if the Elasticsearch server becomes unresponsive or goes offline.**

In fact it has nothing to do with the appender/Elastic being unresponsive : in a lossy configuration, only evaluators will trigger the flushing of the buffer :

- Level evaluator, will flush if an event of a certain lever occurs (ex: FATAL or ERROR), giving the context of the crash (=last logs occuring before the crash).

  ```
  <evaluator type="log4net.Core.LevelEvaluator">
      <threshold value="ERROR"/>
  </evaluator>
  ```
- Time evaluator will flush if a certain time interval has elapsed

  ```
  <evaluator type="log4net.Core.TimeEvaluator">
      <interval value="300"/>
  </evaluator>
  ```

For my purpose I finally decided to configure a TimeEvaluator with a 5 minutes interval.
This way, as long as there is no more than 200 logs (my buffer size) per 5 minutes, no log will be discarded and the impact on performance is kept low.